# /broadcasting/auth endpoint always fails with 403 (access denied) error when trying to authenticate with Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, broadcasting

I haven't been able to find too many answers on specifically authenticating broadcasting using Sanctum. I'm trying to implement a basic event that broadcasts to pusher, but I keep getting a **403** error when trying to connect to `/broadcasting/auth`. Firstly, yes, I have uncommented the BroadcastServiceProvider in `/config/app.php`. Here is an extract from my Broadcast service provider:

app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

I authenticate using Sanctum and all of my endpoints live in the api.php file. I'm not sure whether I should be declaring the `Broadcast::routes` there, as I've seen some people allude to it, but I don't really know what difference it makes as it still gives me the same error. I also don't even know if calling `auth:sanctum` middleware is valid here. I mean, I know it works for all of my api routes, but I'm not sure about in this Provider file.

I'm trying to hit the `/broadcasting/auth` endpoint with Postman, while including my Sanctum Authorization header (Bearer [token]) in the request, but it just gives me a **403**.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: if you remove this "['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]", no more 403 ?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue but I was able to resolve it by adding the channel on which I'm broadcasting on in the channel.php file inside the route directory.

**channel.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('request_channel.{device_id}', function ($user, $device_id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) \App\UserDevice::find($device_id)->user_id;
});
```